# Why is this field not showing up in the results?

Tags: t-sql

When I run the selects below, I do not get Field3 in the result set, why?

```
    Select 
        a.Field1,
        a.Field2,
        a.Field3,
        sum(IsNull(a.Field4, 0)) AS SomeAlias1,
        a.SomeField5,
        a.SomeField6,
        a.SomeField7
From SomeTable a
INNER JOIN SomeView1 v on v.au = a.au
inner join (select Username, House from Users userBuildings where UserName = @UserName) as userHouses on userHouses.au = a.au
WHERE
(((where claus logic here....

Group BY    a.Field1, 
        a.Field2, 
        a.SomeAlias1, 
        a.Field3,
        a.Field4,
        a.Field5,
        a.Field6,
        a.Fielf7
)

Select 
    transBudget.Field1,
    transBudget.Field2,
    transDiscount.Field4,
    ... some other fields...
    IsNull(transDiscount.Actual, 0) - IsNull(transBudget.Actual, 0) AS Variance 
from (Select * from Transactdions Where TransDesc = 'Budget') AS transBudget
    FULL OUTER JOIN
    (Select * from Transactions Where TransDesc = 'Discount') AS transDiscount
        ON transBudget.Market = transDiscount.Market AND transBudget.SubMarket = transDiscount.SubMarket
```

I see every field except Field3 for some reason and it's beyond me how the heck this can happen.

Comment: 2nd query -> Select  
    transBudget.Field1, 
    transBudget.Field2, 
    transDiscount.Field4 ... you have not selected Field3 ???

Comment: see my comments to NYSystemsAnalyst.

Comment: that's fine, select the one from the table that you want to return in the final result.

Comment: See I don't know which I want to return.  The results should be split by Budget vs. Discount.  So whatever is related to that row (budget or discount) should show up.  I may have to restructure this entire select statement...that's prob my problem.

Answer (score 2):

In the second part of your query, you are missing field 3.

```
Select 
    transBudget.Field1,
    transBudget.Field2,
    transDiscount.Field4,
    ... some other fields...
    IsNull(transDiscount.Actual, 0)
```

You appear to have two separate SQL queries there.  The first one contains Field3, but the second one does not.

Comment: Here's the problem with adding it in the second query.  Both transDiscount and transBudget have a Field3 so how do I return ONE Field3 back? It's like ok, both have a Field3 so which do I choose??  So what I mean is transBudget.Field3 or transDiscount.Field3??  both of those have a Field3

Comment: It looks like you are doing a self join from the Transactions table to itself.  Therefore, both transBudget and transDiscount will have the same fields.  How did you decide to use Field1 and Field2 from transBudget vs using Field4 from transDiscount?

Comment: thank you NY, did not know that's how that works with self joins.

Comment: actually no, if I pick and choose between TransBudget.Field3 and transDistcount.Field3, I only get a specific value....for example Field3 could be 'Budget' or 'Discount'.  If I just choose one like TransBudget to return, all I get is all 'Budget' Field3's back...there are not just Budget Field3 types but also Discount and  I need for both types to come back....

Comment: also I don't see how this is a self join.  I just see 2 separate select statements not related at all to each other.

Comment: and if the first query did have Field3 then why at least aren't those records showing that column at least for the first select's results, and the rest maybe would be null for the second selected statement if I had it as the original query right?  But I get NO Field3 period.

Comment: can I say I hate T-SQL,...I really do

Comment: If you want both Field3's to appear in your result set, then you need to specify both of them (transBudget.Field3 and transDiscount.Field3).  It is a self join because although you are calling them transBudget and transDiscount, the data for these two is coming from the same Transactions table that is specified in the sub-select statements.  The first select statement should return Field3.  Based on what you posted in your question, you should be receiving two separate result sets.  The first one should contain Field3, but the second should not.

Comment: If this does not help, I suggest editing your question to include the table layout and a better description of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: ok thanks, I just thought it felt weird to specify the same field name twice even though it was aliased with 2 diff aliases in the second select.  I'll try that out.

Comment: I don't want both Field3's to show up.  I want ONE Scenario per row.

Comment: I end up with 2 columns instead : ....Actual | Budget | 5226 | rest of columns for a given row....  I only want the Scenario that relates to the specific rows, not both.